# EOL when scanning string literal error in Python

Tags: python

```
def print_lol(the_list, level):
    for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            print_lol(each_item)
        else:
            for tab_stop in range(level):
                print("\t", end=")
        print(each_item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("\t", end=")
               # ^ missing quote (")
```

Comment: Please don't be greedy and post a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: it is the answer, The OP tries to run the script and gets that error...

Comment: @doukremt: why? This is a correct answer. Vote to close the post instead if you feel the question should not have been asked.